# How to Set inner data to CKEDITOR using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR for the advanced Post Insert purpose, when i am going to update a Post then i want to fetch text to CKEDITOR from the database. So how can i set the value to CKEDITOR?

Here is the Code which i tried(Failed),

```
 <script>
 // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
 // instance, using default configuration.
 CKEDITOR.replace('post_value');
 CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(<?php echo $obj->postdata; ?>);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The instance key should be the same as the element ID

Try changing:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(<?php echo $obj->postdata; ?>);
```

to

```
CKEDITOR.instances['post_value'].setData(<?php echo $obj->postdata; ?>);
```

This assumes that `$obj->postdata;` returns an html string also

Comment: Try `CKEDITOR.instances['post_value'].setData('<?php echo $obj->postdata; ?>');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {              
    evt.editor.setData('<?php echo $obj->postdata; ?>');
});
</script>
```

or

```
<textarea id="editor1"><?php echo $obj->postdata; ?></textarea>
.
.
.
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
</script>
```

Either way, make sure the script comes after textarea.